# Windows.h error

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, include, header

I am getting error :

```
WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
```

Help needed.

Comment: Compiling C++ code may result in really crazy strange error messages that nobody can understand, but my award goes to you for not understanding a really, really clear error message. On the other hand, if you did understand the error message, you should have written in this question what you already did to solve the error, otherwise it's really generic.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the second inclusion, from (presumably) your code. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/2ab6862f-0d90-467a-b283-f62f6aef96fe/) is a MSDN forum thread about the problem, it seems it can also depend on your exact inclusion order.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `/showIncludes` preprocessor directive, the output window will display all the includes *before* the error.  There you can find which file erroneously includes `windows.h`.

Then find out why this file is needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you use MFC, do not use `#include <windows.h>` manually anywhere in your code. MFC includes it in its own way and you already have access do all declarations of this header.

Answer (score 2):

Oh well, the error message seems say just everything.

When you've created an MFC app, it already included windows.h.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the best way to fix errors is to *do as the error message says*.

Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Use `#include <afx.h>` instead of `#include <windows>` when working with mfc.